# Remove Portion of HTML in EWS EmailMessage Body

Tags: c#, html, css, exchangewebservices

I would like to remove a portion of `HTML` content of `EWS EmailMessage` `.Body.Text` value before replying via `ResponseMessage` in `C#`

The content to remove are as follows, and they contain clickable and non-clikable `html` buttons.

I see that we can't declare our own custom tags, so I am unable to use `string.replace` by locating custom html tags.

May I know if there are workarounds for my task, such as placing the content below in a placeholder, etc?

```
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif">&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="30%" style="width:30.0%;background:#17202A;padding:4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt;display:inline-block">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:white">ACTION: ADD
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif">&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="30%" style="width:30.0%;background:#17202A;padding:4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt;display:inline-block">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:white">ACTION: MINUS
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif">&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="20%" style="width:20.0%;background:#3A69C2;padding:4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt;display:inline-block">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:white"><a href="mailto:test.com?subject=[MULTIPLY];body=ACTION:%20MULTIPLY"><span style="color:white;background:#3A69C2;text-decoration:none">MULTIPLY
</span></a><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif">&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="20%" style="width:20.0%;background:#3A69C2;padding:4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt 4.5pt;display:inline-block">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="font-size:11.5pt;font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:white"><a href="mailto:test.com?subject=[DIVIDE];body=ACTION:%20DIVIDE"><span style="color:white;background:#3A69C2;text-decoration:none">DIVIDE
</span></a><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif">&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the Id attribute of the html tags https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp to identify the tags that you want to remove ?

Comment: I have tried `ID` attribute for `headers` and `tables`. However, after getting the email body content, the `ID` information could not be found, and only `summary` attribute shows up. So I ended up using `summary` attribute with an empty `table` until I find a better solution..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove the table containing the Multiply and Divide buttons and that they will not be found anywhere else in the document we can use those in combination with XPath to find the table and remove it. You could possible use the inbuild `XMLDocument` class but as this it HTML I'll recommend using [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) (available as a nuget package) to parse the HTML.

You'll end up with something like:

```
//Create a HTMLAgilityPack Document
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
//Load the email body
doc.LoadHtml(EmailMessage.Body.Text);
//Select the ancestor table of the link we're interested in
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@href='mailto:test.com?subject=[DIVIDE];body=ACTION:%20DIVIDE']//ancestor::table");
//Remove the table
node.Remove();

//Get the new email body
string newBody = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

You may need to tweak a little to get you there but hopefully this is a good start.

Comment: Thank you @Jon, I will give it a try. Will this work for `Add` and `Minus` as well, since they are not a clickable button?

Comment: This removes the parent table ... what precisely do you want to remove. Perhaps edit your question to include the desired output.